# ASP.net Maintaining CurrentUICulture for bookmarks and linked urls

Tags: asp.net, localization, clean-urls, currentuiculture

So I have a website that is in two different languages and I've set it up to pull text from a resources file based on CurrentUICulture.

I have two link buttons that a user can click to switch between english and russian.

Example:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU");
```

And this switches the language just fine. But I'd like to have the current language somehow reflected in the current URL for bookmarking purposes or for sending out links to a page ina specific language. 
Like on of these examples:

- **www.mysite.com/contact/index.aspx?lang=ru**
- **www.ru.mysite.com/index.aspx**
- **www.mysite.com/ru/contact.aspx** (altough this directory doesnt actually exist)

I'm also wondering how to best segregate Google Analytics data between the two different languages.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend an HttpModule to read this parameter out. Have you thought about just storing this in a persistent cookie for the user as well?

See this link -

[Is it safe to use an HttpModule for localization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952525/is-it-safe-to-use-an-httpmodule-for-localization)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the language parameter in the url, and parse this parameter in [InitializeCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.initializeculture.aspx) to set the `CurrentUICulture`. You can use querystring or routing for the language parameter.

In addition to url, you can use other [state management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) options as fallbacks to decide the language. However, it is usually good to be able to reset the state with a url.

For the "switch language" button in ASP.NET, you can use:

- `<asp:Hyperlink>`, with the language
  parameter in NavigateUrl
- `<asp:LinkButton>`, with
  Response.Redirect in the event
  handler

#### See Also:

[Best way to handle URLs in a multilingual site in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82380/best-way-to-handle-urls-in-a-multilingual-site-in-asp-net)